# AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor appendPixelBuffer using ASScreenRecorder

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to record screen with ASScreenRecorder. The problem is this works sometimes and sometimes it shows **Warning: Unable to write buffer to video** on logs which is because of this line of code :

```
BOOL success = [_avAdaptor appendPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer withPresentationTime:time];
                    if (!success) {
                        NSLog(@"Warning: Unable to write buffer to video");
               }
```

It is returning NO inconsistently. Any idea why ? and how to solve it ?

I have referred most of the related questions and nothing worked for me. 
This is the library with open issue : https://github.com/alskipp/ASScreenRecorder/issues/15

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution maybe not the efficient one but it is doing the trick for me.
Sleep the thread for 0.001 (choose any timeInterval this one is working for me without any noticeable skips in frames)

```
BOOL success = [_avAdaptor appendPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer withPresentationTime:time];
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.001]; // this line added
      if (!success){
            NSLog(@"Warning: Unable to write buffer to video");
      }
```

I hope to find a better solution in future.